# How to put() and get() from a multiprocessing.Queue() at the same time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, queue, multiprocessing

I'm working on a `python 2.7` program that performs these actions in parallel using `multiprocessing`:

- reads a line from `file 1` and `file 2` at the same time
- applies `function(line_1, line_2)`
- writes the function output to a file

I am new to multiprocessing and I'm not extremely expert with python in general. Therefore, I read a lot of already asked questions and tutorials: I feel close to the point but I am now probably missing something that I can't really spot.

The code is structured like this:

```
from itertools import izip
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process, Lock

nthreads = int(mp.cpu_count())
outq = Queue(nthreads)
l = Lock()

def func(record_1, record_2):
     result = # do stuff
     outq.put(result)

OUT = open("outputfile.txt", "w")
IN1 = open("infile_1.txt", "r")
IN2 = open("infile_2.txt", "r")

processes = []
for record_1, record_2 in izip(IN1, IN2):
     proc = Process(target=func, args=(record_1, record_2))
     processes.append(proc)
     proc.start()

for proc in processes:
     proc.join()

while (not outq.empty()):
     l.acquire()
     item = outq.get()
     OUT.write(item)
     l.release()

OUT.close()
IN1.close()
IN2.close()
```

To my understanding (so far) of multiprocessing as package, what I'm doing is:

- creating a queue for the results of the function that has a size limit compatible with the number of cores of the machine.
- filling this queue with the results of `func()`.
- reading the queue items until the queue is empty, writing them to the output file.

Now, my problem is that when I run this script it immediately becomes a zombie process. I know that the function works because without the multiprocessing implementation I had the results I wanted.

I'd like to read from the two files and write to output at the same time, to avoid generating a huge list from my input files and then reading it (input files are huge). Do you see anything gross, completely wrong or improvable?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue I see is that you should pass the queue object through the process instead of trying to use it as a global in your function.

```
def func(record_1, record_2, queue):
     result = # do stuff
     queue.put(result)

for record_1, record_2 in izip(IN1, IN2):
     proc = Process(target=func, args=(record_1, record_2, outq))
```

Also, as currently written, you would still be pulling all that information into memory (aka the queue) and waiting for the read to finish before writing to the output file. You need to move the `p.join` loop until after reading through the queue, and instead of putting all the information in the queue at the end of the `func` it should be filling the queue with chucks in a loop over time, or else it's the same as just reading it all into memory.

You also don't need a lock unless you are using it in the worker function `func`, and if you do, you will again want to pass it through.

If you want to not to read / store a lot in memory, I would write out the same time I am iterating through the input files. Here is a basic example of combining each line of the files together.

```
with open("infile_1.txt") as infile1, open("infile_2.txt") as infile2, open("out", "w") as outfile:
    for line1, line2 in zip(infile1, infile2):
        outfile.write(line1 + line2)
```

I don't want to write to much about all of these, just trying to give you ideas. Let me know if you want more detail about something. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! 
The way you wrote it in the end of your post is exactly how I had it written before trying to implement multiprocessing. Kudos for me haha :)

"You need to move the p.join loop until after reading through the queue"

I'm not sure I understood clearly where you mean.

Comment: "You also don't need a lock unless you are using it in the worker function": with this you mean that I should pass it through like you suggested for the queue, right?

Comment: @Macspider For the `p.join` I just mean move that entire for loop `for proc in processes:
     proc.join()` down under the `while` loop.  And yes to the lock question, just put it in as another argument to `func` and pass it through just like the queue.